# Handoff between Watch and Phone Parse.com doesn't show user as logged in

Tags: ios, parse-platform, watchkit, handoff

So I've pretty much finished my first WatchKit app for one of my iOS apps, in which I use Parse.com as a backend. I've setup a shared app container and shared keychain as per the Parse documentation and everything is working fine.

However I started to implement handoff to allow users to open my app on there phone from the lock screen if they're using it on there watch. However sometimes when the app opens, the user does not appear as logged in.

There seems to be 2 situations, only 1 of which seems to do this.
• If the app was already open in the background, when the user opens the app via handoff and the lock screen, the user is logged in correctly.
• However, if the app is not open in the background, when the user opens the app via handoff and the lock screen, the user will not be logged in.

I have a feeling it's an authentication issue with the app not being authenticated with Parse when opened in the background, but I'm not sure.

Any help would be appreciated here, as it's my last thing to work out.

Comment: I currently believe this is a bug with Parse and have reported it: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/445538432320999/

Comment: This is possibly fixed in Parse 1.8.1 (maybe 1.8.0). I'm testing a bit more before I close this.